# Import module from an untrusted name

Tags: python, security, python-import

This piece of code I'm working with is supposed to import an internal module based on its name. The name of the module is given by an outside source, so it cannot be trusted.

```
def import_module_from_name( name ):

    # will raise an ImportError if the module does not exist
    module = __import__( modulename )

    filename = module.__file__
    if "<internal_path>" in filename:  # check if the module can be loaded
        return module
    raise ImportError  # the module exists but must not be loaded from here
```

If for some reasons we have a malicious package in our `PYTHONPATH`, the `__import__( modulename )` would execute it. For instance:

```
$> echo "print 'Got u'" > /usr/lib/python/site-packages/malicious_package/__init__.py
$> python
>>> import_module_from_name( "malicious_package" )
Got u
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in import_module_from_name
ImportError
```

I know that most of the usual packages have a `if __name__ == "__main__"` instruction to avoid any code execution when importing them, and that's exactly what a malicious package wouldn't have in this case.

Now, considering that we reject any possibility of having a malicious package installed in our `PYTHONPATH` (yes, I know this is a very big assumption...), are you aware of a *well-known* and *widely installed* package for which an `import` could have an unexpected behaviour in this very context? (I just want to have a very simple proof of failure to show that we need to rewrite this thing ASAP)
And do you see another way to check that the module we want to load is within the trusted path without importing it and without handling an exhaustive list of the trusted modules?

Comment: What kind of behaviours are unexpected? FWIW assignments and class and function definitions are also executable code so almost every module you import will execute code, unless it's empty. Many well known and widely installed modules change the way other modules work (seaborn and matplotlib).

Comment: @Goyo By "unexpected behaviour" I mean anything that could have a visible side effect: some entries in the log file, a new file created somewhere on the server, a connection established with another server, a modification of some environment variable, ...

Comment: I am not aware of any side effects at import time *outside* the python environment in which the module is imported.